# Empezar proyecto Symfony 6 con php 8 error de composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer

ME dispongo a empezar un proyecto privado usando symfony 6.1 y php 8.1 pero al ejecutar

`symfony new miproyecto --version="6.1.*"`

Me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a poner el disable-tls a true como dice el error, pero tampoco funciona porque symfony requiere que este activo.

He editado los ficheros php.ini.development y php.ini.production para activar la extension de openssl pero sigue haciendo lo mismo, y el phpinfo() me lo muestra como desactivado.

Comment: pero hay no sale que sea un error...

Comment: "you can disable this error..." es un error, de todos modos se ha solucionado reinstalando el composer, supongo que por alguna razón tenía una versión antigua.